# How to test browser window behaviour with JEST?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm writing a SPA (React) application and I'm using Redux and Jest for the application.
Now, in my reducer, I do have an action which removes some initial HTML (splash screen) from the screen after all the content is loaded. This is checked with the `window.onload()` event.

Howver, when I'm invoking this with JEST, an error is thrown saying that `window.onload` is not a function.

How can this be resolved, below is my reducer.

```
export const reduxReducer = (state = initialReducerState, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case ReduxActions.FADE_OUT_AND_REMOVE_SPLASH_SCREEN:
                // Set an event handler to remove the splash screen after the window has been laoded.
                // This ensures that all the content is loaded.
                window.onload(() => {
                    document.getElementsByClassName("splash-screen")[0].classList.add("fade-out");

                    // Set a timeout to remove the splash screen from the DOM as soon as the animation is faded.
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        let splashScreenElement = document.getElementsByClassName("splash-screen")[0];
                        splashScreenElement.parentNode.removeChild(splashScreenElement);

                        let styleElements = document.getElementsByTagName('style');
                        for (let i = 0; i < styleElements.length; i++) {
                            styleElements[i].parentNode.removeChild(styleElements[i]);
                        }
                    }, 500);
                });



           // Returns the updated state.
            return {
                ...state,
                appBootstrapped: false
            }
        default:
            return {
                ...state
            };
    }
};
```

And off course my test file:

```
it("Update 'appBootstrapped' to true when the 'FADE_OUT_AND_REMOVE_SPLASH_SCREEN' action is invoked.", () => {
    // Arrange.
    const expectedReduxState = {
        appBootstrapped: true
    };

    // Assert.
    expect(reduxReducer(undefined, { type: FADE_OUT_AND_REMOVE_SPLASH_SCREEN })).toEqual(expectedReduxState);
});
```

Comment: Reducer should be pure function. That's why you have problems testing it.  From Docs. "Given the same arguments, it should calculate the next state and return it. No surprises. No side effects. No API calls. No mutations. Just a calculation"

Comment: And where should the logic of modifying the DOM be located?

Comment: Well, there are options. For example a middleware or action creator. But definitely not reducer, because making reducer not pure kinda ruins testability, reproducebility and such.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I will for sure remove the functionality from the reducer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `window.onload` to whatever you want. So the easiest is to set it to spy like this :

```
global.onload = jest.fn()
```